# In-App purchase runs well in SandBox but rejected by review team

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

We have been rejected by review team recently for a In-App Purchase issue.

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 8.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks. 
>   Specifically,
>   your application’s In App Purchase Transaction cannot be completed.
>   The steps to reproduce are:
>
> 1. Launch app
> 2. Navigate to purchase/recharge tab
> 3. Proceed to purchase one of the In-App Purchase products
> 4. In-App Purchase confirmation window appears
> 5. Confirm purchase
> 6. In-App Purchase results in an error

BUT! In-App Purchase runs well in sandbox! We checked log on our server, but we can't find any receipt verification logs. It seems that purchase completion window didn't appear at all.

We found we would use the following code sometimes:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Is that the ONLY reason? T.T

EDIT:
We had released several versions before. This time we added a new product. But we forgot to add its identifier to the following array.

```
-(void)requestProducts
{
    if (_products) {
        return;
    }
    NSSet* identifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                          @"identifier",
                          @"new identifier",  // forgot this line
                          nil];
    SKProductsRequest* _request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:identifiers];
    _request.delegate = self;
    [_request start];
    _requestProcessing = YES;
}
```

So the following code will return nil:

```
-(SKProduct*)getProduct:(NSString *)identifier
{
    if (_products) {
        for (SKProduct* product in _products) {
            if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
                return product;
            }
        }
    } else if (!_requestProcessing) {
        [self requestProducts];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

When user buy a product:

```
-(void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    if (![self isNetworkOK] || ![SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NotifyPurchaseFailed object:productIdentifier];
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", productIdentifier);
    SKProduct* product = [self getProduct:productIdentifier];
    if (product) { // the new identifier gets nil here
        SKPayment* payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    } else {  // calls the deprecated api
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}
```

BUT, it runs well in sandbox.

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed: // may break here
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea? All the products on itunes connect are in Approved state except the new one. The new product is in Waiting for Review state.

Comment: did you add your In-App-Product to the new App-Version for approval? In-App-Products need to be added to the version for approval.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did add when I submitted. This In-App-Product was rejected as well. I had to modify it. Now it's in Waiting for Review state.